# "dial unix /tmp/docker.sock: connect: permission denied" when running docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fedora

I just switched to a new computer at work, and I can't figure out why I'm getting this issue. I've searched on a lot of SO threads and other websites, but nothing fixed it yet.

My OS is Fedora 29. Also I'm a noob with docker, so I'm honestly lost in all this.

So basically everytime I'm running `docker-compose up`, I'm getting this error:

```
nginx-proxy        | dockergen.1 | 2019/10/15 08:23:40 Error retrieving docker server version info: Get http://unix.sock/version: dial unix /tmp/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
nginx-proxy        | dockergen.1 | 2019/10/15 08:23:40 Error retrieving docker server info: Get http://unix.sock/info: dial unix /tmp/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
nginx-proxy        | dockergen.1 | 2019/10/15 08:23:40 Error listing containers: Get http://unix.sock/containers/json?all=1: dial unix /tmp/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
nginx-proxy        | dockergen.1 | 2019/10/15 08:23:40 Watching docker events
nginx-proxy        | dockergen.1 | 2019/10/15 08:23:40 Error retrieving docker server info: Get http://unix.sock/info: dial unix /tmp/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
nginx-proxy        | dockergen.1 | 2019/10/15 08:23:41 Docker daemon connection interrupted
```

**docker group**

I've seen a lot of people suggesting to create the `docker` group and add the current user in it, but it doesn't work for me, even after logging back in again and rebooting.

```
$ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw----. 1 root docker 0 Oct 15 09:58 /var/run/docker.sock
$ whoami
ave
$ groups ave
ave : ave wheel dialout docker
```

I've also tried `sudo setfacl -m user:ave:rw /var/run/docker.sock`, which didn't work either.

**docker**

I've tried uninstalling docker and reinstalling it, stopping the docker daemon and restarting it, `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up`.

It doesn't matter if I'm running `docker-compose up` with or without `sudo`, the same error occurs.

**docker-compose.yml**

My `docker-compose.yml` file is like 200 lines long, so here's a part that I think is related to this issue? Tell me if more is needed.

```
services:
  nginx-proxy:
   build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile-nginx
   container_name: nginx-proxy
   ports:
    - "80:80"
   environment:
    - DEFAULT_HOST=<a host name>
   volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
   depends_on:
    - web
    - gateway
    - processing
```

Comment: add this `privileged: true` in your Docker compose file. also run docker-compose up with sudo if its sudo issue. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/123

Comment: @Adiii `privileged: true` fixed the issue, thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add

```
privileged: true
```

> This was merged already. To enable on your containers use:

```
my_service:
 privileged: true
```

You can check this [issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/123#issuecomment-60128963).